# Convert an int array of 1 and 0 to corresponding decimal number

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I have a 2D array of size 100x128. This consists of 1's and 0's of dtype int64. I need to convert this to each column into 16 symbols of 8 bits with corresponding decimal number.

For example, In a smaller scale, consider this 5x8 case with 2 bit symbols.

```
[[1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1],

[0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1],

[1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0],

[1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0],

[1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

I need to convert this to

```
[[2 1 1 1],

[1 2 1 3]

[2 2 3 0],

[2 3 1 2],

[3 0 1 1]].
```

So In my case, I need to first divide each row of 128 bits into 8 bit chunks and get the decimal value of the corresponding binary number, which should give me 100x16 2D array.

I have tried first reshaping the (100,128) 2D array into a (100,16,8) 3D array. But I am not sure how to do the binary to decimal conversion considering 3rd dimension as binary strings.

Comment: Please post what you have tried & in what way(s) it was deficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), take the matrix product of every `2` bit sequence by the corresponding values in the `2**np.arange(n_bits)` which can be done with the `@` operator, then `reshape` again:

```
n_bits = 2
pows = (2 ** np.arange(n_bits))[::-1]
(np.reshape(a, (-1, n_bits)) @ pows).reshape(-1, a.shape[1]//2)

array([[2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 0],
       [2, 3, 1, 2],
       [3, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: You can get 4-5x performance boost if you replace `* pows).sum(1)` by `@pows` ( dot product)

Comment: Ah of course... Always appreciate your feedback @Brenlla :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using numpy you could do something like:

```py
bits_count = 2
bit_weights = 2**np.arange(2)[::-1]
data = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
) 
(data.reshape((data.shape[0], -1, 2)) * bit_weights).sum(axis=2)
```